# generating files with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, build-process, gulp

I've got a project with several files called `setup.js` in various sub folders in my `/src` folder. I'd like a gulp task to copy all the `setup.js` files to a `/dist` folder and preserve the sub folder structure. This part is easy.

The tricky part is I would also like to generate an index.html file beside each of the `setup.js` files in the `\dist` folder. The index.html file will be exactly the same for all of them except that it will need to reference the `setup.js` script using a path relative the the `/dist` folder. I know I could use some like [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template) to dynamically render an html file but I don't know how I would pass the path the `setup.js` into it. And I don't know how to create an `index.html` for each `setup.js`.

So the resulting folder structure I'm going for would look something like this

```
/src
    template.html
    /blah1
        setup.js
    /blah2
        setup.js
/dist
    /blah1
        setup.js
        index.html
    /blah2
        setup.js
        index.html
```

Any idea on how I would do this?

Alternatively if someone can link me to some detailed docs/examples/tutorials on Gulp that might explain how to go about domething something like this I would greatly appreciate it. I haven't found many good articles that actually explain what's going on behind the scenes in Gulp and it's hard to find examples that go beyond the trivial `src | uglify | concat | dest` use case.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is not actually what you want but I have similar task as you mentioned. I need to generate part of my `index.html` based on the minified JS/CSS. What I did is to use `jade` to make the `index.html` as a server side dynamic page, so when user requested it can be rendered accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately I can't rely on any server side rendering because I'm planning on serving these files directly out of a JS Bin so I don't really have any server. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm certainly no expert on gulp or node, so feel free to correct me/add to my answer...

I've tried to replicate a similar directory structure to what you describe here...

Uses [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-tap) and [gulp-template](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-template)

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var template = require('gulp-template');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/**/**.js', { base: './src' })
    // tap into the stream to get the current file and compile
    // the template according to that
    .pipe(tap(function (file) {
      gulp.src('./src/template.html')
        // compile the template using the current
        // file.path as the src attr in the template file
        .pipe(template({
          sourcefile: file.path
        }))
        // not sure about this line but I'm sure it could be better
        // splits the path on the / and then uses the second to last
        // item in the split array (which is the current directory, minus src plus dist)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/' + file.path.split('/')[file.path.split('/').length - 2]))
    }))
    // finally put the javascript files where they belong
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

**template.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="<%- sourcefile %>"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Beginning Directory Structure**

```
.
|____dist
|____gulpfile.js
|____src
| |____bar
| | |____setup.js
| |____foo
| | |____setup.js
| |____template.html
```

**Final Directory Structure**

```
.
|____dist
| |____bar
| | |____setup.js
| | |____template.html
| |____foo
| | |____setup.js
| | |____template.html
|____gulpfile.js
|____src
| |____bar
| | |____setup.js
| |____foo
| | |____setup.js
| |____template.html
```

Comment: Didn't know about gulp-tap. This looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see @brbcoding's solution so I ended up coming up with this solution. I think I like his usage of tap more though:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
var lodash = require('lodash');


var replaceWithFile = function(filePath, outName) {
    return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
        var gulpContext = this;

        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err,data) {
            file.contents = new Buffer(data);
            file.path = path.join(path.dirname(file.path), outName);

            gulpContext.push(file);
            callback();
        });
    });
};

var template = function(data, options) {
    return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
        var resolvedData = {};

        for (key in data) {
            if(typeof data[key] === 'function') {
                resolvedData[key] = data[key](file);
            }
            else {
                resolvedData[key] = data[key];
            }
        }

        file.contents = new Buffer(lodash.template(file.contents.toString(), resolvedData, options));
        this.push(file);
        callback();
    });
};


gulp.task('test', function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/setup.js')
        .pipe(replaceWithFile('src/indexTemplate.html', 'index.html'))
        .pipe(template({
            challengeFolder: function(file) {
                return path.dirname(file.relative);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out1'));
});
```